# What chemistry topics should I learn if I have to do research in microfabrication (ex. photolithography) and ionic liquids (QSPR, synthesis)?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I'm starting a PhD and my research topic involves microfabrication (photolithography, etc.) and also ionic liquids (including QSPR and possibly synthesis). The thing is, I know close to nothing about chemistry, my background is in aerospace engineering. I am ready to make a big investment in time to learn whatever I need to reach to the point where I can do research in these topics, but I also can't take all the courses of a Chemistry undergrad at this point. What topics should I learn, and what can I skip? If you could recommend me some books/online classes or courses that would be a bonus! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Have you gotten any input from the graduate advisors or faculty in your program?

Comment: The present question is probably a bit too general to receive a fitting answer. There is a (limited) survey of recommended [resources](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry) which may become more useful after discussion and narrowing the addressed target(s) with your supervisor. *If focused  in time and topic*, a search with keywords on publishers' / societies' websites (e.g., [mdpi](https://www.mdpi.com/search?q=photolithography), [ACS](https://pubs.acs.org/action/doSearch?AllField=photolithography&startPage=)) may be an inspiration.

Comment: Thank you Todd and Buttonwood. I'll ask faculty too, good idea. Buttonwood, I know the question is a bit broad. I just try to read papers or books related to those two topics and I realize I lack of a lot of background knowledge. I'm wondering what learning path should I take in order to understand these topics better. I'll probably review the basics with Oxtoby's book. But then should I look into physical chemsitry, inorganic chemistry? And thank you for the resources!